# Reading cucumber Jvm tag programmatically

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, java-annotations

I am trying to reuse my existing integration test cucumber Gherkin scenarios for performance test using Gatling. Integration tests are written in restassured.io and cucumber JVM. What I am trying to do is adding a new tag to existing integration test, something like @Performance_REQ_noOfRequest_RESP_responseTime.

So I want to know is there any way programmatically read cucumber tag so that I can extract request and response value and send it to Gatling test.

Sample Gherkin is 
Feature: End point to get employee information

@Regression @Performance_Req_1000_Resp_100s
Scenario: Get employees
When I send request to /api/employees
Then I should see a list of employees

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the tags of a Scenario using the Before or After Hook like for example:

```
@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {

    scenario.getSourceTagNames();
}
```